# Array to CollectionType in Symfony 3.4 forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, symfony-forms

I've got the array Cart of the entities, and I want to generate general form, which looks like on the screen.

[image]

As you see, I want to have editable field Quantity in each row, which represents the Cart entity, and I want to have ability to update all of them at once.

```
class Cart
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="carts")
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="carts")
 */
protected $product;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $quantity;

/*gettes & setters */
}
```

For now, I have form, which wants to receive CollectionType, to work on it, but - I have only an array of entities, so It's dumping LogicalException.

What I need to do - there is any way to parse array to CollectionType, or maybe I could take group of cart entities from database in another way than that?:

```
$carts=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cart::class)->findByUserId($user);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example of how to do what you're looking to achieve in the [Symfony Documentation on How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_collections.html).

For your specific use case, you will want to create a `UserCartsForm` and a Separate `CartsForm`.

In your `UserCart` add the `carts` field as a `CollectionType`.
Symfony will then process the field as a series of forms.

*src/AppBundle/Form/UserCart.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as FormType;

class UserCartsForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder->add('carts', FormType\CollectionType::class, [
             'label' => false,
             'entry_type' => CartsForm::class,
             'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
         ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Add the fields you want editable on your form to the CartsForm

*src/AppBundle/Form/CartsForm.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as FormType;

class CartsForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder->add('quantity', FormType\IntegerType::class, [
           'label' => false
            //...
         ]);
         //...
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cart::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your controller, reference the user entity as your `UserCartsForm` data.

*src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\UserCartsForm;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

   /**
    * @Route('/user/{id}/carts')
    */
   public function userCartsAction(Request $request, User $user)
   {
      $form = $this->createForm(UserCartsForm::class, $user);
      $form->handleRequest($request);
      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         //... process entity
         //$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
         return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route');
      }

      return $this->render('user_carts_form.html.twig', [
          'form' => $form
      ]);
   }
}
```

Then you should be able to easily retrieve the data from your twig template to render as you would like.

*app/Resources/views/user_carts_form.html.twig*

```
{% form_start(form) %}
   <table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <td>Name</td>
       <td>Quantity</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for cart in form.carts %}
   {% set cartEntity = cart.vars.data %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ cartEntity.product.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ form_widget(cart.quantity) }}</td>
       <td><a class="button" href="{{ path('remove_cart_action', { id: cartEntity.id }) }}">Delete <icon/></a></td>
   <tr>
   {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{% form_end(form) %}
```

---

**Update for Entity Constraints**

By default Symfony will use all constraints (`Default`) assigned to the entity when validating your form causing `$form->isValid()` to return false.

> https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/groups.html
>
> If no groups are specified, all constraints that belong to the group
> `Default` will be applied.

To resolve the issue, use [Validation Groups](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/validation/groups.html) to separate the entity constraints and declare the desired groups on their respective form(s).

Example:

*src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"})
     */
    private $username;
    
    //...
}
```

Then to [use your validation group(s)](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/validation_groups.html) on the desired form, in this case `RegistrationForm`, you declare the desired group in the `AbstractTye::configureOptions` as one of the `OptionsResolver:$defaults`.

*src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationForm.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class RegistrationForm extends AbstractType
{
    //...

     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults([
             'data_class' => User::class,
             'validation_groups' => ['registration']
         ]);
     }

}
```

Now the `User::NotBlank` constraint will only apply for the `RegistrationForm::isValid()` or any other form that declare the registration validation group.

Comment: needed to change few things to match with my project in 100%, but at least it works great. Thanks man, i owe you a huge huge beer :D

Comment: But one more thing - how to submit & persist it correctly? Form is not getting into isValid && isSubmitted statements, so it's only changes the cart entity "locally", without saving it to the database

Comment: Check the form errors to see why it is not passing as valid. I'm not sure what constraints you have on the form or entity. You will need to create groups if the constraints are on the entity. Also ensure you have the CSRF token in your form if they are enabled as that will prevent the form from being valid.

Comment: It throws and error with plainPassword field from User entity, which have "NotBlank" assert. Is there way to properly obey it?

Comment: And after deleting this assert, everything works fine, but if you can help me with dealing with that error it would be great... Maybe kinda "if" while submiting form? I dont know...

Comment: @D_Jedrzejewski updated answer with validation group example.